# Set item dimensions to parent container in MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I wanted to share my solution for an issue I've been facing a lot when working on my MAUI project, in hope it could help clarify if some people are in the same situation, especially regarding Bindings.
Here is the issue : I have a MAUI control (here a Button) within a Grid, and I want to set its height so it takes all the available space vertically.
My problematic was to find the correct way to do so, ideally with as few code behind as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with : `HeightRequest="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=Height}"`.
It'll query the height of the closest Grid type parent in the Ancestor tree, and use it as button height.

As an example, this code :

```xml
<Grid Grid.Row="0" ColumnDefinitions="*,*" VerticalOptions="Fill" Background="Aqua">
    <Button ContentLayout="Top" Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=Height}" 
        Margin="15" ImageSource="remove_bold_white48.svg" StyleClass="CheckNo"/>
    <Button ContentLayout="Top" Grid.Column="1" 
        Margin="15" ImageSource="check_double_white48.svg" StyleClass="CheckOk"/>
</Grid>
```

Will result in this layout :

[image: Button layout]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's an actual question here, but if the objective is to have a button take up the available vertical space in the `Grid` row(s) containing it, with little or no code-behind, you may want to experiment with leaving its vertical options at the default.

[image: android screenshot]

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ItemDimensionToParent.MainPage">
    <Grid 
        ColumnDefinitions="*,*"
        Background="Aqua">
        <Button 
            FontFamily="ok-cancel-icons"
            FontSize="60"
            Text="&#xE800;"
            Grid.Column="0" 
            Margin="15,0"
            BackgroundColor="#B11400"/>
        <Button 
            FontFamily="ok-cancel-icons"
            FontSize="60"
            Text="&#xE801;"
            Grid.Column="1" 
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            BackgroundColor="#14A34A"
            Margin="15,0"
            Padding="5" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: There is no question, I just wanted to share my solution Q&A-style has I have been facing this problem for long before being able to find a solution. Thanks for the suggestion tho, the default VerticalOptions seems to be working as well.